# Best Practice for Async Objection Creation in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Good day,

I am new to VueJS and I’ve been trying to learn and adhere to best practices with respect to creating objects and passing them into a component. My only other exposure to frontend frameworks is Angular 1, so my questions may reflect practices from that paradigm.

Every example and article I’ve seen passes handles objects like this:

```
<my-person id="eg1" :name="person.name" :age="person.age"></my-person>

var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#eg1',
  data: {
    person: { name: 'john', age: '100' }
  }
})
```

Which makes sense to me, but then I got to thinking, “What if I wanted to load this person in from an API?” I should move the API call logic into a service, but where would I call that service from?

- In the data:{} object itself?
- Before the Vue component boiler-plate via a Person object?
- Would I make the api call and load it into the store via VueX and then pass in that stored state?

The examples below kind of highlight a lot of my confusion. For non-trivial examples, what is the best practice for handling async object creation and subsequently passing it into a component?

```
<div id="eg2">
  <my-person :name="person.name" :age="person.age"></my-person>
  <!-- Is it an anti-pattern to just send a (possibly large) object in as a 
       prop? Or do you want to define it in the data of this view/component? -->
  <my-person :person="classPerson"></my-person>
  <my-person :person="apiPerson"></my-person>
  <my-person :person="instantiatedPerson"></my-person>
</div>

// What would instantiating a person out here mean for updating its state?
let person = new Person(api.getPerson())

var example2 = new Vue({
  el: '#eg2',
  data: {
    person: { name: 'john', age: 100 },   // Standard method.
    classPerson: new Person('john', 100), // What would instantiating a Person here mean for updating its state?
    apiPerson: api.getPerson(),           // Is it considered bad practice to make the api call here and have it return a Person?
    instantiatedPerson: person
  }
})

// ./models/person-model.js
export default class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }
}
```

I apologize if this question is covered, but I’ve read through a bunch of articles and examples and I couldn’t really find clear answers as the how this is done in the “real world”. Any help, or links to articles, would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Reading *Methods, Computed, and Watchers in Vue.js* by Sarah Drasner https://css-tricks.com/methods-computed-and-watchers-in-vue-js/

From the article:

> use **data** to track changes to a particular property that we’d like to be reactive
>
> **Computed** properties allow us to define a property that is used the same way as data, but can also have some custom logic that is cached
> based on its dependencies.
>
> **Methods**: These are exactly what they sound like they might be (yay, naming!). They’re functions that hang off of an object—typically the Vue instance itself or a Vue component.

Unlike in angularJS where everything can live on `$scope` in Vue the state and methods should be split up. In the example below `this.getPerson()` is called from the `created` lifecycle method https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'eg2',
  data() {
    return {
        person
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getPerson() 
  },
  methods: {
        getPerson() {
            api.getPerson().then(response => this.person = response.data) 
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

or with Vuex

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'eg2',
  created() {
    this.getPerson() 
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['person'])
  },
  methods: {
        ...mapActions(['getPerson']),
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the various hooks. Makes sense now!